# Appcelerator titanium runtime error

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have an existing project that was not developped for more than a half a year.
Now i need to support it.
I have updated Titanium SDK and all other libraries used in the project.
But right after the launch of the application on the device i have runtime error.
The screenshot of the error:

[image]

I'm surprised because this was the stable version of the app ready for production. So only after updating libraries this error occurs.
Here's some parts of the code:

This is the 'index' view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Alloy>
<Widget id="drawer" src="nl.fokkezb.drawer">
    <Window module="xp.ui" role="leftWindow" >
        ......
    </Window>
    <NavigationWindow platform="ios" role="centerWindow">
        <Require type="view" src="Home"/>
    </NavigationWindow>
    <Window module="xp.ui" platform="android" role="centerWindow" home="Home">
        <Require type="view" src="Home"/>
    </Window>
</Widget>
</Alloy>
```

and HOME.xml

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="winHome" platform="ios" class="container whiteBackground no-navbar" navBarHidden="true" layout="vertical" opacity="1">
    <Require type="view" src="homeContent"></Require>
</Window>
<Window id="winHome" platform="android" class="container whiteBackground no-navbar" navBarHidden="true" layout="vertical" opacity="1">
    <Require type="view" src="homeContent"></Require>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

and homeContent:

```
<Alloy>
<View id="winHomeContent" class="container whiteBackground" layout="composite" visible = "false">
    <View class="ver">
        .........
    </View>
    <View bottom="0" class="h-size">
        <Require type="view" src="homeFooter"/>
    </View>
</View>
</Alloy>
```

I see that both 'index' and Home views have "Window" tags.
But this exact code was working earlier.

Comment: Your screenshot url need permission !

Comment: Sorry, now should be fixed

Comment: I added it to the post instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.xml` from Doc [nl.fokkezb.drawer](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.drawer)

`centerWindow` role is a `View` not an `Window`

```
<Alloy>
    <Widget id="drawer" src="nl.fokkezb.drawer">

        <Window module="xp.ui" role="leftWindow">
            <Label>I am left</Label>
        </Window>

        <NavigationWindow platform="ios" role="centerWindow">
            <Window>
                <LeftNavButton>
                    <Button onClick="toggle">Left</Button>
                </LeftNavButton>
                <Label>I am center</Label>
                <RightNavButton>
                    <Button onClick="toggle">Right</Button>
                </RightNavButton>
            </Window>
        </NavigationWindow>
        <View platform="android" role="centerWindow">
            <Label>I am center</Label>
        </View>

        <Window module="xp.ui" role="rightWindow">
            <Label>I am right</Label>
        </Window>

    </Widget>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: i've tried it and now i have other error:
`TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()`
I have this line multiple times and then app fails

Comment: Can post the console log ? Because it's another problem

Comment: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UfXZO1u_50Vu8JnYrlxxGGIP01sklXT-Rlm2JCCw4Os/edit?usp=sharing) is the link to complete log file

Comment: This is a `[TRACE]` not `[ERROR]` !!

Comment: Yes, but then app crashes.
Looks like entire loop or stack overflow.

Comment: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cnrqVGAA-4gRg45MHT_yOBQ4muIzTjWhGK6jqniWPQI/edit?usp=sharing) is the android monitor error log.
Looks like some error in android theme configuration.
Will investigate further.

Comment: Finaly solved last issue by playing with android theme now it looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>`

Comment: Good news ! , please make my answer is the correct answer for your main question

Answer (score 0):

The `module="xp.ui"` from your `index` transform `Window` into `View` for Android. On your `Home.xml` you have 1 `Window` for both platform but the code is the same ! So, in your `Home.xml` replace `Window` by a `View` like this :

```
<View id="winHome" platform="android" class="container whiteBackground no-navbar" navBarHidden="true" layout="vertical" opacity="1">
    <Require type="view" src="homeContent"></Require>
</View>
```

Your problem is on both platform ? iOS ? Android ?
By the way, your screenshot is not public so we can't see it.

Comment: i fixed the screenshot.
Problem is android specific.